# Resizing a model / armature to the same size as another one

Tags: mesh, armature, transforms

Does somebody know a simple way to scale a model and armature to the same size as another? I have a few models that are too large but when i try to scale them down (select all meshes and armature, press S and scale to what I want) to the size of a few other ones and apply, and they end up messed up.

Answer (score 0):

After scaling, apply the armature modifier, then apply scale to both model and armature, then add a new Armature modifier to the model, targeting the armature (weights will remain preserved).

If you have previous animations, every loc value keyframes need to be scaled on value (Y axis in graph editor) by the same exact amount, using the value of 0 as pivot point (2D cursor as pivot, set the pivot to frame 1, value 0).